# why laravel ubuntu server take so much space of hard drive

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, redis, memcached

**My laravel server hard drive 140GB is full,
i can't understand why laravel need all this space**

> i check laravel folder size is 1GB and mysql database is 4GB. i
> cleaned my storage logs and views and caches still no space.

i used:

```
ubuntu 20.04
laravel 8
redis server 
memcached server
laravel horizon
mysql database
nginx server
```

**1-why laravel need all this space??**

**2-how i can clean my server (running server, i need all my data and my configs)**

**update:**

> after search on all server folders size i found this records

```
155922466       /
149611964       /var
128542076       /var/log
76998556        /var/log/syslog.1
45773836        /var/log/syslog
20042652        /var/lib
18252444        /var/lib/mysql
3669391 /snap
1958038 /snap/google-cloud-sdk
1846628 /usr
1528680 /var/lib/snapd
1022012 /var/lib/snapd/snaps
982095  /snap/google-cloud-sdk/191
975939  /snap/google-cloud-sdk/190
928920  /var/www
928904  ***laravel-project
858288  /var/log/syslog.5.gz
852952  /var/lib/mysql/ **mysql database
819620  /var/log/journal
```

Comment: is this safe to delete /var/log/syslog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After Deep Search**

> **laravel dosn't take all this space or mysql database.**

**system log who take much space**

```
/var/log/syslog
```

**How to fix?**

```
1- delete old /avr/log/syslog.x / syslog.x.gz
2- check which proccess caused this errors
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
3- fix your error and delete old log.x/log.x.gz files
```